# Track incoming payment of an address using cardano-db-sync

Tags: cardano-node, cardano-db-sync, blockchain-explorer

I have a cardano-node with cardano-db-sync installed. In this node, I also have a separate database named `CDT`, and a web UI to connect to this `CDT` database.

I defined an address named `addr1xxxxxx` which I want to track incoming payment. In the web, I display this address as QR code to users.

When users see this QR code, they have to send a certain ADA to this address within a certain time. If they do send enough ADA, they will be redirected to the next step and so on.

What I want to do this to get know whether users have sent enough ADA to this address or not. I can check `cexplorer` database to know this, but in many cases I am afraid that `cardano-db-sync` is not synced fast enough to get the latest from the blockchain.

I have heard of webhooks services of blockfrost or tangocrypto. They maybe a good solutions. But it relies on third-party services.

Can you suggest another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Oura](https://github.com/txpipe/oura) which gets you a tail feed of events. Should be the fastest solution not relying on third parties.